# Why is "Fufu" in the following sentence object complement rather than direct object? 'I called my pug "Fufu" .'

Tags: syntactic-analysis, objects, complements

> I called my pug Fufu: subject...object...object complement(Introducing English Grammar, p.93)

Yet if I say:

> I give my pug some water.

then pug would be indirect object and some water would be direct object. At least that is what I believe.

So my question is how to distinguish these two situation?

Comment: You don't need to because with names, the noun before the name regardless: my son John, my dog Fufu regardless of where it is in the utterance, sentence or phrase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation given in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary makes the distinction clear. In this dictionary the pattern "VNN" is that for transitive verbs with a direct object (N) and an indirect one (N), the objects being noun phrases. the patterns "VN-N" and "VN-ADJ" are those of transitive verbs that have a direct object and a complement (which can be a noun phrase (-N) or an adjective (-ADJ).

The way to tell between "VNN" and "VN-N" is that in this latter case the noun phrase "-N" tells something about "N", the object of the verb.

In "I give my pug some water.", "water" tells you nothing about the pug. In "I call my pug Fufu.", "Fufu" tells you that the pug has a name and what that name is.

*Examples from OALD*

- She considered herself lucky. VN-ADJ
- They elected him president.  VN-N
- I sold Jim a car. VNN

Comment: It has zero to do with objects, direct or indirect.

Comment: It's not as simple as whether it says something about the dog. "I gave my dog some water" (indirect object) indicates that the dog has some water; "I named my dog Fufu" (object complement) indicates that the dog has a name. "I found my dog annoying" (object complement) doesn't really say anything about the dog, but about your feelings.

Comment: @StuartF If you have "some water" in mind (as it should be the case since you are making a comparison with "I named… Fufu."), you should say "DO", unless there is something I overlooked. // It seems to me that my characterization takes care of a lot of possibilities; however, your comment raises a serious question, and  I can't quite resolve it except insofar as it seems that putative attributes could perhaps be considered assimilable.

Answer (score 1):

**(2)** The structure **S - V - IO - DO** (I gave my dog a bone; I bought my wife a Lambo) can **usually** (though not always; see the exceptions, the different semantic readings, mentioned by Huddleston & Pullum below) be recast as

- **S - V - DO - to [recipient]** (I gave a bone to my dog.)

or

- **S - V - DO - for [beneficiary]** (I bought a Lambo for my wife.) (I called him a taxi.)

> As Rodney D. Huddleston and Geoffrey K. Pullum say: The indirect
>   object is characteristically associated with the semantic role of
>   recipient ... But it may have the role of beneficiary (the one for
>   whom something is done), as in 'Do me a favour' or 'Call me a taxi';
>   and it may be interpreted in other ways, as seen from examples like
>   'This blunder cost us the match', or 'I envy you your good fortune'.
>   [[Nordquist;
>   ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/indirect-object-grammar-1691161)]

........................

On the other hand, **(1)**

> An object complement is a noun, a pronoun, or an adjective that
>   follows a direct object to rename it / add an attribute in a concise
>   manner, or state/describe what it has become / been made / been named. The structure is **S - V - DO -C[obj]**
>   ....
>
> *Verbs That Attract Object Complements*
>
> - Verbs of *making* (to make, to create, to elect ...) and
> - *naming* (to name, to call, to dub ...) often attract an object complement. In the examples below, the object complements are in
>     italics and come immediately after the direct objects.
>
>   - He makes her *happy*.
>   - They named her *Heidi*. (or They named her *'Heidi'*.)
>
> However, lots of other [semantic] types of verbs can take an object
>   complement. For example:
>
> - They painted the kennel *purple*. (a resultative construction; the referent of the DO has been transformed)
> - They consider him *stupid*. (a depictive construction, describing the DO's referent's (considered) state)
> - They consider Liverpool *champions*.
> - They caught him *napping*.
> - I found the guard *sleeping*.
> - I declare this centre *open*.
> - I proclaim you *King*.
> - We consider fish *spoiled* once it smells like this.
> - I consider him *a man* now.
> - To obtain a man's opinion of you, make him *mad*. (Physician and poet Oliver Wendell Holmes)

Those verbs such as *elect, appoint, make, choose, deem, assign, name, select*, and *designate*, used to indicate the resulting condition / state / position of a person, place, or thing that the action of the verb occasions, are called *factitive verbs*.

> An object complement is not always one word. It could be a phrase. For
>   example:
>
> - I found the guard *sleeping in the barn*.
> - We all consider her *unworthy of the position*.
> - I proclaim you *King Joachim of Crato*. [[GrammarMonster; heavily modifed](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_complement.htm)]

..............

The possibility of ambiguity remains when the object complement is a noun, though it is usually only encountered in schoolboy humour:

- *"Call me a taxi!"*
- *"You're a taxi!"*