# What is the function of "accountable?"

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the function of "accountable?" I know it is an adjective describing people but is it a direct object?

> I want to hold the people accountable

Comment: _The people_ is the direct object. It's a noun. _Accountable_ is an adjective. Direct objects have to be nouns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grammar analysis: why is "Fufu" in the following sentence object complement rather than direct object](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533114/grammar-analysis-why-is-fufu-in-the-following-sentence-object-complement-rath) One example in E Ashworth's answer is '_They consider him stupid_. (a depictive construction, describing the DO's referent's (considered) state)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an object (or objective) complement. From ["Paint the Town Red: Adjectives as Object Complements" at Cambridge University Press's World of Better Learning](https://www.cambridge.org/elt/blog/2021/10/26/paint-the-town-red-adjectives-as-object-complements/):

> - I painted the walls *yellow*.
> - She left the door *open*.
> - The new rules made my job *harder*.
>
> In all of these sentences, the adjective in italics describes the
> object noun (underlined) not the subject noun (the walls are yellow,
> not me). This structure is only possible with a limited number of
> verbs, all of which indicate a cause or change of state: the walls
> were yellow after I painted them; she caused the door to stay open (by
> not closing it), and the new rules caused my job to become harder.
> Some common verbs that are used with object complements are *leave*,
> *hold*, *find*, *keep*, *set*, *make*, *paint*. However, many of the phrases are highly idiomatic: that is, while you can paint walls any
> color, there is a limited number of adjectives that can be object
> complements after verbs like *hold*:
>
> - hold the door *open*
> - hold the administration/government (or any official) *accountable*
> - hold someone *responsible*
> - hold something *still/steady*

Comment: The [Green Conspiracy](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111065/15299) comes under that rubric. _shoot him dead, bury him alive, find him alive/dead, want him alive/dead,_ etc.)